# Reducing synchronization scope

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have implemented a EhCache buffer for performance issues i had with database (MYSQL). But instead of directly storing and retrieving from EhCache, i wrote a buffer on top of it. So only when the method flush is called the data will be stored in the original EhCache. Operations like get(), isKeyPresentCache() will be processed by the buffer first. IF the data not available it will redirect the call to the original Ehcache. Now about the data I am handling..... One Map has the mapping between property and the list of profiles that has the value for that property. Another map which has the profile name against the propertyValue wrapper. So the *get()* operation will first look in the *propertyToProfile* find the latest profile and get the value from *profileToPropertyValue*. If there is no data present, the call will be made to EhCache.

Here is the Buffer Class I implemented....

```
public class Buffer<K, V>  {

    private final Map<String, Wrapper<K,V>> profileToPropertyValue;
    private final Map<K, List<String>> propertyToProfile;

    private final Cache cache = new Cache();

    private final Object lockObject;

    public Buffer() {
        this.profileToPropertyValue = new HashMap<>();
        this.propertyToProfile = new HashMap<>();
        lockObject = new Object();
    }

    public void flush(String id) {
        Wrapper<K, V> wrapperData;

        synchronized (lockObject) {
            wrapperData = profileToPropertyValue.get(id);
        }

        if (wrapperData == null)
            return;

        Map<K, Wrapper> addedEntriesMap = wrapperData.getAddedEntriesMap();
        Set<K> deletedKeys = wrapperData.getDeletedKeys();

        synchronized (lockObject) {
            profileToPropertyValue.remove(id);
            flushPropertyToProfilesMap(addedEntriesMap.keySet(), id);
            flushPropertyToProfilesMap(deletedKeys, id);
        }
    }

    private void flushPropertyToProfilesMap(Set<K> properties, String profile) {
        for (K property : properties) {
            List<String> profiles = propertyToProfile.get(property);

            if (profiles == null)
                continue;

            profiles.remove(profile);

            if (profiles.isEmpty())
                propertyToProfile.remove(property);
        }
    }

    public void put(String profile, K property, V value) {
        Wrapper<K, V> wrapper = getWrapperData(profile);
        wrapper.putAddEntry(property, value);

        addInProperyToProfilesMap(profile, property);
    }

    private void addInProperyToProfilesMap(String profile, K property) {
        List<String> profiles = getProfilesForProperty(property);

        synchronized (lockObject) {
            profiles.remove(profile);
            profiles.add(profile);
        }
    }

    private List<String> getProfilesForProperty(K property) {
        List<String> profiles = propertyToProfile.get(property);

        if (profiles == null) {

            synchronized (lockObject) {

                profiles = propertyToProfile.get(property);

                if (profiles == null) {
                    profiles = new ArrayList<>();
                    propertyToProfile.put(property, profiles);
                }
            }
        }
        return profiles;
    }

    private Wrapper<K, V> getWrapperData(String profile) {

        Wrapper<K, V> wrapper = profileToPropertyValue.get(profile);

        if (wrapper == null) {

            synchronized (lockObject) {

                wrapper = profileToPropertyValue.get(profile);

                if (wrapper == null) {
                    wrapper = new Wrapper<>();
                    profileToPropertyValue.put(profile, wrapper);
                }
            }
        }
        return wrapper;
    }

    public void remove(String profile, K property) {
        remove(profile, property, null);
    }

    public void remove(String profile, K property, V value) {
        Wrapper<K, V> wrapperData = getWrapperData(profile);
        wrapperData.putDeleteEntry(property);

        addInProperyToProfilesMap(profile, property);
    }

    public boolean isPropertyInCache(K property) {

        synchronized (lockObject) {

            List<String> profiles = propertyToProfile.get(property);

            if (profiles != null) {

                String latestProfile = profiles.get(profiles.size() - 1);

                Wrapper<K, V> wrapper = profileToPropertyValue.get(latestProfile);

                if (wrapper.availableInAddedMap(property))
                    return true;

                if (wrapper.availableInDeletedMap(property))
                    return false;
            }
        }

        return cache.isPropertyInCache(property);
    }

    public V get(K property) {

        final List<String> profiles;

        synchronized (lockObject) {

            profiles = propertyToProfile.get(property);

            if (profiles != null) {

                String latestProfile = profiles.get(profiles.size() - 1);

                Wrapper<K, V> wrapper = profileToPropertyValue.get(latestProfile);

                if (wrapper != null) {

                    V v = wrapper.getAddedValue(property);

                    if (v != null)
                        return v;

                    if (wrapper.availableInDeletedMap(property))
                        return null;
                }
            }
        }

        Wrapper<K,V> d = cache.get(property);
        return (d == null) ? null : d.v;
    }
}
```

This buffer class is in a multi-threaded system. Hundreds of threads will be using my *Buffer* instance and performing put(),remove(),get() operations all the time.  So I gotta thread-safe my states. Each maps are related by *'profile'*. But for synchronization, I created a dummy *'lockObject'*. But once I finished, thread safing the code, there is a lot of synchronization blocks involved. I am not sure that I am using the synchronization blocks in correct manner as well. Also I want to know if I use the ConcurrentHashMap instead of the HashMap, can I remove any of the synchronization blocks I have added ?

In the getProfilesForProperty() method I have used Double Null checks to minimize the synchronization blocks scope. I am currently reading about the double null check method and getting a bad feeling about it. Is there any other means of minimizing the scope of the synchronization ?????

Comment: Main reason for sync here is keeping both those maps in... well, in sync. Wouldn't you do that, it could happen, that profileToProperty isn't matching the content of propertyToProfile - synchronization makes access to pair of those field look like a single operation. In the end - no, ConcurrentHashMap won't do the trick, because you cannot make 2 maps share a lock.

Comment: I too thought so Filip. Thanks for clarifying. I have edited my question adding one more item.